# Put property from parameters into a android build config with a default value using gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, parameter-passing, buildconfig, android-buildconfig

I would like to grab a parameter from gradle command line `-Pfruit=Apple`

And then put this parameter into a `BuildConfig` for every `buildType`.

I'm trying to achieve using:

`buildConfigField("String", "env", "\"${project.fruit}\"")`

Unfortunately I don't know how to set default value like `"Pear"` there, and how to set it for all build types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
buildConfigField("String", "env", project.hasProperty('fruit') ? '"' + project.fruit + '"' : '"Pear"')
```

Comment: You need to define string literal in gradle file as `'"Pear"'`, otherwise it will not be able to resolve it.